# Nao é possível Importar arquivo csv no pandas

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, pandas, csv

Boa galera, estou tentando importar um arquivo csv no pandas através do código abaixo:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('pop.csv')
```

Ele não encontra o arquivo em hipótese alguma!

Obs.: O arquivo está no caminho do Sistema MacOS: /Users/sistema/Documents/dados

e apresenta o seguinte erro:

---

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 data = pd.read_csv('pop.csv')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
684     )
685
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
687
688

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
450
451     # Create the parser.
--> 452     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
453
454     if chunksize or iterator:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in **init**(self, f, engine, **kwds)
944             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
945
--> 946         self._make_engine(self.engine)
947
948     def close(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
1176     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
1177         if engine == "c":
-> 1178             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
1179         else:
1180             if engine == "python":

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in **init**(self, src, **kwds)
2006         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
2007
-> 2008         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
2009         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
2010

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pop.csv'

​

---

**Ja tentei as seguintes soluções:**

```
 data = pd.read_csv('/Users/sistema/Documents/dados/pop.csv')

 data = pd.read_csv('/Users/sistema/Documents/dados/pop.csv', sep = ',', encoding = 'utf-8')

 data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/sistema/Documents/dados/pop.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')

 data = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/sistema/Documents/dados/pop.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')

 data = pd.read_csv('./Users/sistema/Documents/dados/pop.csv')

 data = pd.read_csv('.\Users\sistema\Documents\dados\pop.csv')

>>>>>>>> error desse ultimo com a barra invertida:
```

File "", line 1
data = pd.read_csv('.\Users\sistema\Documents\dados\pop.csv')
^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

```
data = pd.read_csv('\\Users\\sistema\\Documents\\dados\\pop.csv')

data = pd.read_csv('.\\Users\\sistema\\Documents\\dados\\pop.csv')
```

Alguém ja passou por isso ao tentar importar o csv e conseguiu solucionar? Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o usuário se chama `sistema` e o arquivo `pop.csv` está na pasta `/Users/sistema/Documents/dados/`, os comandos abaixo devem funcionar:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('~/Documents/dados/pop.csv')
```

Se não funcionarem, é porque o arquivo `pop.csv` não está na pasta informada.

Comment: Marcus, acabei de testar dessa forma e nao funcionou! =(

Hoje consegui "resolver" baixando outra base de dados chamada epi.csv.

O Arquivo pop.csv esta na mesma pasta onde está o novo arquivo que baixei! Consigo abrir o epi.csv, mas o pop.csv nao abre por nada! =(

Obs.: O arquivo do python também esta na pasta.

Vou trabalhar em cima da pasta epi.csv.